# How do I change the link JQuery requests relating to the url?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, api

At the moment I have the top of the code like this:

```
$.getJSON(' https://api.roleplay.co.uk/v1/player/' + "END-LINK", function(data)
```

What I want is that the "END-LINK" bit will be the end of my url - for example, if my url is www.link.com/player.html/76561198062083666 I want it to add those numbers at the end to the jquery request so it will get the api "https://api.roleplay.co.uk/v1/player/76561198062083666"

Comment: So is `END-LINK` a local variable you want to **send** to the API, or do you want to **retrieve** this ID sent **from** the API and assign it to a local variable?

Comment: I want to send the local variable from the link to the API, and then retrieve the values from it so I can assign the values to local variables

Answer (score 3):

I think what you want is to retrieve the ID from the link and send it to the API.

```
var endLink = window.location.href.substr(window.location.href.lastIndexOf('/') + 1)
$.getJSON(' https://api.roleplay.co.uk/v1/player/' + endLink, function(data){...})
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to query your player ID, you **would** assign it to a local variable, and then pass that local variable to your **[`.getJSON()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/)** function just as you have, expect without the quotes:

```js
var end_link = 76561198062083666;

$.getJSON('https://api.roleplay.co.uk/v1/player/' + end_link, function(data) {
  console.log(data);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Note that I have replaced `END-LINK` with `end_link`, as you **cannot** have hyphens in variable names (the parser will treat it as subtraction).

Also note that you will be **unable** to retrieve your information through `.getJSON()`, as RolePlay.co.uk is transmitting a **[`No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Origin)**, meaning they disallow people from querying it in accordance with **[Cross Origin Resource Sharing (CORS)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS)**.

This is typically handled on the server, but considering you don't have access, you can bypass it by adding the argument `--disable-web-security` to your browser launcher.

Hope this helps! :)

Answer (score 0):

[Obsidian Age](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2341603/obsidian-age)  told you very well what you can do to solve your problem.
If I'm not wrong, you want to send the local variables from the link to the API, and you can do it in this way:

```js
var endLink = window.location.href.substr(window.location.href.lastIndexOf('/') + 1)
$.getJSON(' https://api.roleplay.co.uk/v1/player/' + endLink, function(data){
  console.log(data);
  }
);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```